# How to include custom JS files in to React create app

Tags: jquery, reactjs, reactive-programming

I had js files under public folder i want to include these js files in to react components which are under src component folder in react create application?

Answer (score 44):

Please read [Using the `public` Folder](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/docusaurus/docs/using-the-public-folder.md).

In general we recommend installing packages from npm and using `import` to access them from the source. But if you must use a prebuilt JS file that you don’t want to import, you can add it to the `public` folder (for example, `public/mylib.js`) and then add this to `public/index.html`:

```
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/mylib.js"></script>
```

Then you can access the global variable from your app, for example:

```
const mylib = window.mylib;
```

And then use it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

Put them in the same folder as your react components and simply import them to you react components like so:

```js
// importing your js file called jslibrary.js
// make sure that the file path is correct!
import { function1 } from './jslibrary.js'
```

You also have to make sure that you are exporting your function / variables in your jslibrary file, like so:

```js
export function function1() {
  //... do stuff
}

let myVar = 1234;
export myVar;
```

If you use `export default` on a function or a variable, you don't need to use the brackets like in the above.

For more info, I highly recommend the documentation on [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export).

Comment: Good explanation about the export default and recommended documentation with links.