# How can I load a vanilla js file after React injects its files (bundle.js)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I want to load a non-React (vanilla) javascript file after React injects and loads its files into index.html.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include custom JS files in to React create app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44405718/how-to-include-custom-js-files-in-to-react-create-app)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `<script src="custom.js"></script>` in your index.html. React scripts are just regular JS code so it will be treated the same as a regular script.